# create session to use values inside the same method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, pagination

This is code snippet for load 15 text areas into an `Add_New_Product` form page.

```
public ActionResult Add_Product(int? page)
{
        var dummyItems = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField;
        var pager = new PaginationModel.Pager(dummyItems.Count(), page);

        var model = new AddNewProduct
        {
            ListProductFields = dummyItems.OrderBy(i => i.ProductFieldID).Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),
            Pager = pager
        };

        return View(model);
}
```

Since in this form page has many text areas(like 15) ,I limited with pagination , one text area per one page.

this is the view

[image]

I want use above `ListProductFields` data iteratvely inside same above method.

But once I insert the a value to **first text area** and then go to **next text area** , again if I click previous button , then **first text area**'s added values are disappearing.

I decided to come up with `sessions` , So I changed above code as follows

**Attempt 1:**

```
    public ActionResult Add_Product(int? page, AddNewProduct sample)
    {
        AddNewProduct newmodel = sample;                       

        AddNewProduct newmodels = Session["TemplateData"] as AddNewProduct;

        var dummyItems = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField;
        var pager = new PaginationModel.Pager(dummyItems.Count(), page);

        var model = new AddNewProduct
        {
            ListProductFields = dummyItems.OrderBy(i => i.ProductFieldID).Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),
            Pager = pager
        };

        Session["TemplateData"] = model;

        return View(model);

    }
```

---

**Edit**

**Attempt 2:**

```
    public ActionResult Add_Product(int? page, AddNewProduct sample)
    {
        TempData["AddNewProduct"] = sample;

        AddNewProduct book = TempData["AddNewProduct"] as AddNewProduct;

        var dummyItems = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField;
        var pager = new PaginationModel.Pager(dummyItems.Count(), page);


        var model = new AddNewProduct
        {
            ListProductFields = dummyItems.OrderBy(i => i.ProductFieldID).Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),
            Pager = pager
        };

        sample = model;


        return View(model);

    }
```

But it doesn't keep any value

Comment: I don't see where you are calling `Add_Product` again. It's called once only.

Comment: its on the view page, since it has pagination ,I can redirect to same action

Comment: Try with TempData instead of Session.

Comment: You have 2 unused variables in your `Add_Product` action on the first 2 lines.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you meant `var pager` and `var dummyItems` ?

Comment: No, I meant from the first 2 lines of your controller action: the `newmodel` and `newmodels` variables. From what I can see the `pager` and `dummyItems` variables are used in your view model which is then passed to the view.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I created, because those are need for my `Session` , I think , correct me if im wrong

Comment: Well, you are not doing anything with those variables, so it is the same if they weren't there.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov from this line `AddNewProduct newmodel = sample` to assign `AddNewProduct sample` model values , then this line to `AddNewProduct newmodels = Session["TemplateData"] as AddNewProduct;` , invoke the session and assign those values , is this in wrong path ?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. On the first line you are not assigning `sample` to the model values. You are assigning it to some new variable called `newmodel` which is not used anymore. So you are basically throwing it away. On the second line you are trying to read some value from the session and assign it to another new variable called `newmodels` that you also throw away because you never use it anymore.

Comment: could you please mention way to do this or any resource that I can refer

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is it possible to use a session inside a same method ?