# client side pagination for a form in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pagination, paging

I have **registration form** page that have 15 text areas. since this is large I had to come up with option that limit one text area per one page with pagination.

But once I insert the a value to **first text area** and then go to **next text area** , again gain if I click **previous button** , then **first text area**'s added values are disappearing.

So I thought this model values becoming null when I go to to new page with pagination can ignore, if I do client side pagination for this form

I just followed [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306164725/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012611-1.aspx) to configure client side pagination for a form.

this is relevant controller method

```
public ActionResult Add_Product(int page = 1, int pageSize = 1)
{
        var dummyItems = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField;
        var pager = new PaginationModel.Pager(dummyItems.Count(), page);

        var model = new AddNewProduct()
        {
            ListProductFields = dummyItems.OrderBy(i => i.ProductFieldID).Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList(),
            CurrentPageIndex = page,
            PageSize = pageSize
        };

        // Determine the total number of products being paged through (needed to compute PageCount)
        model.TotalRecordCount = this.db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Count();

        return View(model);      

}
```

But in here also same scenario, page is refreshing and values are disappearing when new page visit.

Comment: better use Jquery for pagination..

Comment: This works only for Displaying some data. If you have inputs you have to save the model in session and update it everytime `Add_Product` is called.

Comment: @adiga can you refer good example for this

Comment: @adiga [this is another atttempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604604/create-session-to-use-values-inside-the-same-method) ,using `session` I try to do this  I wish you could help me with that

Comment: Are these textareas empty or are populating them from DB for editing purposes? What is the model for `dummyitmes`?

Comment: Actually this is a `Create` page so no values , `dummyitmes` I missed this hold on I'll put this